# laravel Image upload and save in MongoDb database

Tags: mongodb, laravel, image, file-upload, eloquent

I am uploading profile picture in laravel,
In my add.blade.php file I've write like this

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="role">Profile Picture :<span class="danger">*</span> </label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="file">
  </div>
</div>
```

in My Controller File my function is like this

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'file' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);

    if($request->hasfile('filename'))
    {

        foreach($request->file('file') as $image)
        {
            $name=$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);
            $data[] = $name;
        }
    }
```

How can i upload image and save it in my MongoDb database??

Comment: Any error occur in your code??

Comment: No error occur,
will you please share how to code to upload image in laravel and store in database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to **multiple images upload** then you can try to do this code:

In your **blade**:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="role">Profile Picture :<span class="danger">*</span> </label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="file[]" multiple>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your **Controller**:

```
$images = $request->file('file');

foreach ($images as $key => $image) {

   if ($request->hasFile('file') && $request->file('file')[$key]->isValid()) {
       $path = $request->file[$key]->store('public/images');
       $path = basename($path);

       $image = new Images();
       $image->photo = $path;
       $image->save();
   }
}
```

Comment: hey Record inserted in database but image isn't add in folder and insert in database too, 
apart from image i am using other fields too..

Comment: You have to link storage folder in your public folder or not?

Comment: and image folder's path is this ?
/var/www/html/hrm/storage/app/public/imges

Comment: you have to run this command `php artisan link:storage` and to make sure the storage folder linked in your public and then try upload the image.

Comment: i got this error
`  There are no commands defined in the "link" namespace.`

Comment: sorry try this one: `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: link was created bit still problem is same image neither insert in folder nor it's name/path store in database

Comment: Ohh Owk Thankq So much @Inzamam for help I do it in another and it's work properly..Thankq So much

Comment: If it helps you mark as right answer for other users to help.

Comment: This Code is also work in controller file
`//Store Image In Folder
        $file = $request->get('file');
        $path = $request->file('file')->store('images');

 $employee->file = $path;
`

Comment: Do you know how to retrieve image from database